# Which c# data structure should blob contents be bound to for optimal line by line processing?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

In an Azure Function, you can use a blob trigger. This trigger can be [bound to a variety of data structures](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-storage/#storageblobtrigger):

- TextReader (input only)
- Stream
- ICloudBlob
- CloudBlockBlob
- CloudPageBlob

When working with log data i.e. data you want to process each line of, which structure should be used to minimise compute time and memory usage?

---

This is the current process I use and it doesn't feel very elegant. May not be relevant but intent is to serialize data to JSON and put into a queue or documentDB.

```
public static void insertBlob([BlobTrigger] TextReader logBlob, TraceWriter log)
        {
            string[] text = logBlob.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
            // Do some stuff
            log.Info(text.Count().ToString());
}
```

Comment: From my experience, there is no way to get the lines other than reading to the end. If you want to minimize computer time and memory usage, maybe you could try queue or documentDB.

Comment: @Jambor-MSFT yes all lines need to be read, and whilst they're tab-delimited they need to be processed so they can go into a queue or docdb. I'm trying to construct an efficient Azure Function to do that. The question is about whether any of object types that a blob input can bind to are more effective for this use case than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a performance perspective, using a stream would be best since that would reduce memory pressure/load time.

In terms of algorithmic approach, you won't do much better than just storing a buffer and processing the line when you see the `'\n'` character. If you're not too worried on performance, etc., I might use what you have just because it's quite simple. Functions will horizontally scale anyway.